# Android: Get user language in ISO 639 alpha-2 code(en, pt, jp...)

Tags: android, locale

I'm trying to get user language with `two-letters` but no success until here.

Use `Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language();` returns code with three digits (eng, por, jap).

Use `substring` method to cut does not work for all codes, so what's the solution?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: yep, it works very well, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `getISO3Language()`, use `getLanguage()` and you will get user language like `en`, `ja`, `pt` etc.

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

Checkout official documentation for more information about [getLanguage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#getLanguage())